# How to change the header title in Mesibo messaging activity

Tags: android, mesibo

I want to remove the default header view or change it to different text. I am using the provided Messaging Activity by Mesibo. I have checked all configuration options but couldn’t find one to edit this.

Screen shot is added.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default header view which you are seeing corresponds to `MesiboRecycleViewHolder.TYPE_HEADER`

You need to create your own view holder and return when the type is `MesiboRecycleViewHolder.TYPE_HEADER`. If not, the default view will be shown.

Refer to this document to learn about how to customize message rendering.

https://mesibo.com/documentation/ui-modules/android/messaging/#customizing-message-rendering

You can also refer to the source code of MesiboActivity and messaging modules in GitHub. Particularly, this file should interest you:

https://github.com/mesibo/ui-modules-android/blob/master/Messaging/messaging/src/main/java/com/mesibo/messaging/MessageAdapter.java#L167

Comment: I was aware of these files and I have seen the codes of demo app. There were few issues I have faced, so I just went for using the default messaging activity. I think for now I can't remove the header with my existing code base.

Comment: Is there any way to change the send button color of the Image Edit activity? I have asked this in one of a previous question. Please help me if there is any solution